# How do I make my SKLabelNode an element that presents a new view in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
class LabelButton: SKLabelNode {
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.atPoint(position)
            if self.contains(location) {
                print ("nothing")
            }
        }
    }
}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let nothing = LabelButton(fontNamed: "San Francisco")
    nothing.text = "nothing?"
    nothing.fontColor = SKColor.white
    nothing.fontSize = 20
    nothing.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
    addChild(nothing)
}

func goToPlanetNothing(){
    var gameScene1 = PlanetNothing0(fileNamed: "PlanetNothing0")


    let transitionEffect =
        SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 1.0)
    gameScene1 = PlanetNothing0(size: (gameScene1?.size)!)
    gameScene1?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gameScene1?.view?.presentScene(gameScene1! , transition:transitionEffect)
}
```

This is the code.  If I go to the simulator, I click the element, but nothing happens.  The code does not crash or show an error, however.

Comment: FYI,  You do not want to print("nothing") and then say nothing happened.  Do you mean you printed nothing, or that nothing was printed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside `touchesEnded()`:

```
for touch in touches {
    if self.contains(touch.location(in: self.scene!)) {
        print("nothing")
    }
}
```

Comment: I used     print("nothing") as a placeholder.  I tried your answer @Christoph, but the label now doesn't show up at all.

Comment: @MadelineCoven I would recommend working on your problem solving skills.  Look at the code Christoph provided.  Nowhere does the code cause a label to disappear.  This means that you did something beyond the scope that Christoph can see.

Comment: The code that I provided surly won't make the label disappear, so there must something else that must have changed in your code.

Comment: @Christoph I rearranged the classes and functions to make it work.

Comment: So is it functioning now as it should?

Comment: @Christoph, it won't present the scene, but the node came back.